# How to anchor groupbox to left but allow groupbox to grow to maxwidth when stretching

Tags: c#, wpf

I was recently trying to help my friend with a WPF layout issue and I can't seem to figure out how to get it working either and it seems like such a simple thing, so I thought I would tap the wealth of knowledge here :)  What he wants is for groupbox1 to autosize to the value of maxwidth and then to stay anchored to the left while the space to the right of the groupbox grows.  So to keep this simple I am just going to post some sample code of the situation now :)  If anyone has some light to shed on the situation please respond.  Thanks everyone!

```
<Window x:Class="GroupBoxTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="147" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="151*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="148" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="355*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GroupBox Header="groupBox1" Margin="14,12,41,8" Name="groupBox1" MaxWidth="450" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid />
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox Header="groupBox2" Margin="12,12,13,8" Name="groupBox2">
        <Grid />
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move MaxWidth="450" to the ColumnDefinition and remove it from the GroupBox.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="148" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MaxWidth="450" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GroupBox 
        Name="groupBox1" 
        Header="groupBox1"
        Margin="14,12,41,8"
        Grid.Column="1">
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox Header="groupBox2" Margin="12,12,13,8" Name="groupBox2">
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: @Dan: You could have noted in your question that you do not need the grid column to actually size as expected, with this solution all elements in the column will only stretch as wide as 450, not just the group box.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `MaxWidth="450"` on the ColumnDefinition will work for the `GroupBox`.

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="355*" MaxWidth="450"/>
```

If the other elements in Column 1 should Stretch further than 450 then you can set `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` for the `GroupBox` and bind `Width` to another element within the same Column.

*`ActualWidth` for a `ColumnDefinition` isn't a Dependency Property, otherwise we could have used that as the source for the Binding*

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="151*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="148" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="355*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Name="sizeElement" Fill="Transparent" Margin="14,12,41,8" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <GroupBox Header="groupBox1" Margin="14,12,41,8" Name="groupBox1" MaxWidth="450" Grid.Column="1"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Width="{Binding ElementName=sizeElement, Path=ActualWidth}">
        <Grid />
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox Header="groupBox2" Margin="12,12,13,8" Name="groupBox2">
        <Grid />
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a workaround using a style like this:

```
<GroupBox Header="groupBox1" Margin="14,12,41,8" Name="groupBox1" MaxWidth="450" Grid.Column="1">
    <GroupBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="GroupBox">
             <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ActualWidth" Value="450">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="450"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>   
                    </Trigger>       
                 </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>    
        </GroupBox.Style>
    <Grid />
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: Thanks H.B. for the answer.  It seems that when the window is shrunk back down, the group box doesn't shirnk.  I haven't played with triggers so I am going ot go look more into this, but thanks so much for the response!!

Comment: Oh i didn't see the clipping that occurred there when sizing back down, it looked as if it was actually working the other way too, there has to be a way to fix that as well...